# Android jfeinstein slidingmenu toggle?

Tags: android

I use jfeinstein slidingmenu in android app and i have parent with this menu and child activity without this menu , the problem is when i return back to parent activity sliding menu stucked and not toggle?

Comment: whenever to navigate to new activity call `toggle` to open or close the drawer it probably solve your problem

Comment: i call toggle of course from a button click and it toggle, then i go to second activity and after press back button i return to the first one but when i try to open menu from the button again it not toggle.

Comment: post some part of code